# Two divs (menu and contents) next to each other with transparent margins

Tags: css, layout, html

I know there are solutions to this problem already. However, I'm looking for a particular solution. The left menubar should be fixed-width while the right contents area should have dynamic width. I can do this.

However, the texts in the menu and contents must NOT start from the edges. There should be a bit of margin on the top and left.

I tried the following CSS code:

```
<div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:400px;width:150px;padding-left:15px;float:left;">
Menu 1<br />
Menu 2<br />
</div>

<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:400px;margin-left:180px;">
Contents...
</div>
```

However, I get a white strip between the menu and contents. All margins must be transparent. Also, the webpage should work in IE9, Chrome and FF.

**My question is, how do I make the texts appear with some top and left margin, without getting that nasty white strip in IE9/FF/Chrome?**

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried using padding to offset the text? Padding happens inside the box, so the padding-area will still have your background colour.

Comment: Yes I've tried that. While it works fine in Chrome, it produces very weird results in IE. IE puts in the text 180px AFTER the end of the menu bar, but the text should be 180px from the site (container) border. Also, I get a small white strip in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdKGv/2/) . Is that what you want?

Comment: That works fine in FF and Chrome. However, doesn't work in IE9. Is there any way to make IE9 render the style the same way Chrome does it?

Comment: Ok I have made some changes, see again.

Comment: Sorry. Produces the same result in IE and also this time doesn't work in Chrome/FF.

Comment: I don't understand, working for me in FF /Chrome and even in IE 7/8/9

Comment: My results: (without overflow) http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/2276/withoutoverflow.png (with overflow) http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/755/withoverflow.png ... Don't know what's going wrong :(

Comment: Do I have to declare a DOM or DTD or something ?

Comment: OK Problem solved! Had to include Strict XHTML DTD. Thanks a lot!